# Java library to parse mysql exception message

Tags: java, mysql

Is there any library in java which parses mySQL exception and give back row/ column or table information. so that I can use the row or column name to fetch and display more appropriate message(custom exception message which i want to include the column or row info).

Currently this is how am doing extracting info, handle few exception cases by using [mysql error codes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-messages-server.html) and pattern marcher to find the info.

Comment: you can use `try-catch` and catch exception by using `SQLException` through this you i'll get error code and error message

Comment: Create one java library which parses MySQL exception for your own, unnecessary exception data store data, Where I can't find a good reason to do so.

Comment: @SamDev if we process batch records from a file, and say batch failed at a point but which column or the which data row(while trying to insert / update it got failed) we don't know about the info. I have to stream the data while the batch processed and display it in UI. If some thing goes wrong i can not show the entire exception message.

Comment: I finally managed to write few files which parses the mysql server errors (defined with in a file copied from the above given URL) and passed exception data. Based on the error code i wrote few conditions and switch cases to get the column and the row information. 
I realized that this question is not generic question and has to deal with the large set of exceptions i request someone to mark this as close.