# Find a particular exception and corresponding message

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-data

My web application runs on Spring (MVC) 4.2.9.RELEASE, Hibernate 5.1.3.Final,  Spring Data 1.8.2.RELEASE, and MS SQL Server (2014).

In the Spring context, I have the following exceptioin hanlder:

```
<bean id="simpleMappingExceptionResolver" class="myproject.CustomMappingExceptionResolver">
...
</bean>
```

to catch and save stack trace. I am able to see the following **deep** in a long stack trace printed in the logs:

```
...... 
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
            at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
            ... 113 more
        Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Transaction (Process ID 73) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:258)
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1535)
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:467)
```

How can I find the following exception class in the above exceptioin hanlder (and given an Exception instance) :

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException
```

**AND** the corresponding message:

```
Transaction (Process ID 73) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
```

Comment: So if I understood correctly you want to get the exception class in your exception handler and its corresponding message. If it is a sqlException check for it and each sql exception has an error code and your database provider has corresponding messages. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46660287/java-library-to-parse-mysql-exception-message If I misunderstood ignore this.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly you need to catch a nested exception. That's a bit tricky, but doable. You need to have a `try-catch` block for the *top level exception* that you expect. In the catch clause, you can use `exception.getCause()` to step down one nesting level at a time, and see if that level is an `instanceof` your SQL exception class. You can also check the message if necessary by using `getMessage()`. If the exception fits your criteria, congratulations you caught it. If not, simply `throw` it again.

Two things to keep in mind:

- this approach may lead to poor performance if many exceptions occur, and only a small fraction of those actually matches your criteria.
- if an exception has no cause, then `e.getCause()` will return `e` itself. Watch out for infinite recursion here.